# Как подготовиться на junior asp.net developer?

Tags: c#

Определился, кем хочу работать, но разумеется к этому нужно подготовиться. Прошу подсказать, как мне подготовиться к профессии junior asp.net developer. Что необходимо читать, знать и т.д.?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, вы немного неправильно ставите вопрос: "Как мне подготовиться к профессии junior asp.net developer?"

Готовиться не нужно. Нужно в целом понять предметную область, там где вы хотите работать, развиваться и потихоньку копать в её направлении. Читать книги - ибо их много, читать форумы, задавать вопросы, делать проекты очень мелкие, мелкие, средние. Отвечать на вопросы на форумах и т.д. Это всё банальные слова, но на самом деле так и есть. Просто нужно целенаправленно двигаться в неком векторе.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте себе цель - написать блог/cms/чат/форум/какой-нибудь сервис. Там сразу и понятно станет, что надо знать. Как напишете, так стало быть вы и готовы :)

Вот вам в помощь ссылка: http://www.techdays.ru/Category.aspx?Tag=ASP.NET

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно знать основы C#. Полезно будет порешать задачи для закрепления теории по C#, например, из задачника Златопольского?

Comment: Без понятия, кто это. Купите книгу по ASP.NET. Там обычно бывает информация и по ASP.NET и по C#. Когда сделаете одну из задач, будете знать C#, ASP.NET, какую-нибудь СУБД, возможно javascript, HTML/CSS и может-быть что-то еще.